# How to run logkeys

Tags: startup

I just installed logkeys from Software center. I am finding it hard to run it. Its documentation page doesnt help much either.
1. How do I run it? 
2. Can I bind the start up with a key combination?
3. How to see the logs?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Add this command to startup application so logkeys will be started automatically during every startup..

Goto-->System-->Preferences-->Startup Applications

[image]

In startup applications preferences click add,it will give you a windows with Name,Command and Comments..

In Name field you can give any name and in Command field type `logkeys --start`    and click save.

Before that you want to specify output location for your log.In terminal type `touch test.log` and then type this `logkeys --start --output test.log` to stop logkeys type           `logkeys --kill` in terminal.

Comment: Post your comments if you have any problem,we will help you

Comment: Karthick, test.log on my terminal isnt giving me anything.

Comment: Do you want to view your logs?Then type `tail test.log` in terminal.

Comment: Karthick, this is what I am getting. ubuntu@ubuntu-XPS-M1330:~$ tail test.log
tail: cannot open `test.log' for reading: No such file or directory

Comment: Uh there is no test.log file..I told you to create a file in the name test.log.To create type `touch test.log` in terminal.And then type this `logkeys --start --output test.log`

Comment: Oops. Sorry. I just made the file and tried your next statement, it gave me got root?

Comment: Then try `sudo logkeys --start --output test.log`

Comment: Duh!!! I needed a "sudo" :) So now thats done, it means I am ready to view the logs?

Comment: Yes now you can view the logs :)

Comment: Glad to help.You are welcome.

Answer (score 4):

### Logkeys quick setup:

- Get Logkeys from GoogleCode project spot:

  ```
  wget http://logkeys.googlecode.com/files/logkeys-0.1.1a.tar.gz
  ```
- Unarchive Logkeys:

  ```
  gunzip logkeys-0.1.1a.tar.gz 
  tar xvf logkeys-0.1.1a.tar
  ```
- Build up Logkeys:

  ```
  cd logkeys-0.1.1a/
  ./configure
  make
  sudo make installl
  ```

In case of `./configure` failure, run:

```
sudo apt-get install build-essential
```

Now, it's important to have the current keyboard map file. You can download the keyboard map files at: http://code.google.com/p/logkeys/wiki/Keymaps

- After downloading the keyboard map file that you need, you can set up logkeys:

  ```
  sudo logkeys -s -m /home/XYZ/Downloads/de.map -o /home/XYZ/loggy.log
  ```

  Where `-s` starts the logkeys deamon, `-m` is the path for the keyboard map file and `-o` the log output file. Logkeys should now begin to dump the capture keystrokes to the defined log file (human readable).
- To stop logkeys:

  ```
  sudo logkeys -k
  ```
- For auto start at boot time:

  ```
  sudo vim /etc/init.d/rc.local
  ```

  and add this to the bottom of the file:

  ```
  /usr/local/bin/logkeys -s -m /home/XYZ/Downloads/de.map -o /home/XYZ/loggy.log &
  ```

If desired, reboot your linux box to check the auto start entry at `rc.local`

```
sudo reboot now
```

And you are done!
Props.

Comment: `$ wget http://logkeys.googlecode.com/files/logkeys-0.1.1a.tar.gz` gives `404 Not Found`.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, I think [the documentation](http://code.google.com/p/logkeys/wiki/Documentation#Usage_how-to) is very understandable; Ask concrete question, if you don't understand something.

The second question, what isn't in the docs, I can anwser with this:

> Click **System > Options > Hotkeys**, *New hotkey*, then give a name, the command is: `logkeys --start --output /path/to/log`(don't forget to change **/path/to/log** to your log location!!!), then click on your new hotkey, and give a key combination. Your thing is ready.

Comment: Thanks B.Roland. I am going through documentation .. and will edit the question accordingly.

Comment: Ok, I'll check it once more today!