# Logkeys and screen capture

Tags: 11.10, software-recommendation, boot, startup

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to run logkeys](https://askubuntu.com/questions/14312/how-to-run-logkeys)

I am a kind of newbie and need to get control over my pupils, i. e. work at a youth home and have to have total control over the internet activity of some of the criminal youths over here.

How do I install logkeys for Ubuntu 11.10 Natty Narwhal and have it running from boot?

I thank you in advance.

Answer (score -1):

Quite possible the best way to get control over their Internet activity is to install a hardware appliance such as the Sonicwall TZ100. These security devices connect between the Internet gateway and the PC, and are platform independent. I am not affiliated with Sonicwall, but I do use it at a high school where I am the tech coordinator with great success. I know money is tight everywhere, but for $339 at [this web site](http://www.sonicguard.com/TZ100.asp), you will not only have an Internet content filtering service, but antivirus, anti-spyware, and Intrusion Prevention for all of the computers. I recommend the TotalSecure 100.

P.S. Ubuntu 11.10 is the Oneiric Ocelot. You might want to clarify that for other answers.