# Cannot start logkeys in ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04

A few days ago I installed Ubuntu 14.04 and I am a newbie on it. Today I installed logkeys but I still cannot find a way to make it work. I tried the command logkeys -s via the terminal and it says ''got r00t?'' so I guess I should make the right configurations to start it as root. I am new to the Ubuntu world and kinda lost in it. Could you help me out on this?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have started the process. Anyaway to start it you should type

```
sudo logkeys --start
```

To see the keystrokes typen you should give to the command the **--output** option and the path of the file where you want to save the output

```
sudo logkeys --start --output /path/to/the/file
```

or you can simply see the logs in **/var/log/logkeys.log**, for example type

```
cat /var/log/logkeys.log
```

For more reference just go to https://code.google.com/p/logkeys/wiki/Logfiles and https://code.google.com/p/logkeys/wiki/Documentation

If it says "got r00t" just type **sudo**

```
sudo logkeys --start --output /path/to/the/file
```

Comment: When I type /var/log/logkeys.log it says logkeys: Non-option argument /var/log/logkeys.log
Usage: logkeys [OPTION]...
Log depressed keyboard keys.  and follows with a list of the keys which is too long to post. Got really confused with this thing...

Comment: OK i think this might be useful 
http://askubuntu.com/questions/14312/how-to-run-logkeys

Comment: This path ''Goto-->System-->Preferences-->Startup Applications'' seems to be missing in ubuntu 14.04. Can I find it through system settings?

Comment: Ok lets take it slowly. First open your terminal and type **sudo logkeys --kill** which will stop log keys if it was started. Second type **cd ~** to go to home directory. Third type **touch keystrokes.txt** to create an output file. Fourth type **sudo logkeys --start --output keystrokes.txt** to start logkeys. Now if it easier for you with GUI open your file manager and go to your home directory. There should be a file we created called keystrokes.txt, open that and see if your keystrokes are saved there. Tell me back if it has worked.

Comment: Thanks Antuan! All worked perfectly, but now I have another problem :) How do I 'translate' all those keys saved in the keystroke file?

Comment: Iam glad i helped you, please can you mark my answer as the right solution so it could be helpful for others too. And second can you show me an example of your logkey output.

Comment: Another think i want to say is that you should always run logkeys as superuser by typing **sudo** otherwise it wont work thats why it says **"got r00t"**, this means that you should have superuser rights to run it.

Comment: This is an example from keystrokes.txt file : 2014-09-21 05:23:13+0300 > d
2014-09-21 05:24:27+0300 > apiti
2014-09-21 05:24:45+0300 > xfij܂
2014-09-21 05:25:14+0300 > furia܂ priv j܂bi܂ wr܂

Comment: Should I change the keymap? I have a Dell Inspiron N5030 laptop.

Comment: it just shows you what you have typed alongside the date and the time when you have typed it,, for example **2014-09-21 05:24:27+0300 > apiti** means that in 21 september 2014 at time 05:24 you have typed _apiti_.

Comment: The thing is that I never typed these unintelligible words so I guess I have to change the keymap. Do you know how?

Comment: what desktop environment do you use? what is your default language?

Comment: The desktop environment is the default Ubuntu 14.04 Trysty Tahr and the default language is Greek but I mostly type in English.

Answer (score 1):

You can run things as root using the `sudo` command, so try `sudo logkeys -s` in the terminal and see if that helps?

Comment: Tried that and it says ''Another process already running? Quitting. (/var/run/logkeys.pid): File exists''. So it seems it's running in the background but if so, how can i find it and open it?

Answer (score 0):

Logkeys when installed already has executables in /bin directory that has setuid to root. So all you have to do is type `llk` to start the keylogger and `llkk` to kill it.